# SwiftUI: avoid horizontal shift on Text view in VStack to replicate camera time label layout?

Tags: swiftui

I want to replicate the layout of the time label in the iOS Camera app in a SwiftUI view.

My test code is this:

```
class TimeTestModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var seconds:Int = 0
    
    var timer:Timer?
    
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(TimeTestModel.tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func tick() {
        seconds += 1
    }
    
}


struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var timeModel = TimeTestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            HStack {
                Text("00:0\(timeModel.seconds)")
            }
            .border(.red)
        }

    }
}
```

It creates this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Using my code you can see how the whole text moves left to right as new text is rendered (I have only done from 0 to 9 for the sake of the example, I know I need more String work to go beyond that...).

In the iOS camera app version you can see the positioning of the whole label does not change as the time changes.

I am not sure how to achieve this in SwiftUI.

How can I change my code to allow digits to update without causing horizontal shift?

Comment: Try adding padding and then center align the text.

Comment: I tried this: `Text("00:0\(timeModel.seconds)").frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)` and I still get H shift.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the font. It appears your font has glyphs that aren't symmetrical which is what's causing your shift. If you notice what you're looking for the bounds of each digit are exactly the same regardless. You may want to explore a balanced, symmetrical font.

Comment: Yes, see below comments in Orb's answer...

Answer (score 1):

Like `Yrb` mentioned in his comments, this can be solved using a non proportional Font. So I achieved the wanted result by making this change:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text(timeModel.timeString)
            .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .medium).monospacedDigit()).  <<-- HERE!
    }
    .border(.red)
}
```

Now the Text has zero horizontal shift.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. This is a great contribution.